# Always show more records in Lightning Experience for Related Lists?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

In Aloha there was for Related Lists at the bottom a link to always show more records in related lists:

[image]

We clicked this ALWAYS and either did it several times or hacked the url like this: rowsperlist=9999999. The result was to see all related records. That was great!

Now in Lightning we see only 4 records at a glance, which is very poor. I did not find a customization to show more:

[image]

**Question**

Is there any way to get make it show more records at a glance without clicking the "View All" Button? Using "View All" is mostly bad for the usability, because the users want to see the list embedded in the context and not separated and isolated in a new view.

Comment: There is currently no way to do this. You can upvote this https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br1rAAC

Comment: @Paul we actually found a way to hack-injecting the aloha related list straight into lightning. This is technically a very evil hack but the result is an enormous boost of productivity. We had no time to wait for this. Unfortunately there is NO feasible way to do this cleanly and with reasonable efforts as Lightning Component.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Summer 19 it becomes possible. Salesforce introduced "Enhanced Related Lists" where admin can control number of records displayed in the related list.

> **How**: From the related lists component in the Lightning App Builder, select Enhanced List from the Related List Type dropdown (1). You can customize how many records to display at once, and choose whether to show the list view action bar.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_lex_enhanced_related_lists.htm

[image]